# Only JavaScript Dynamic Array Field Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

I think so there is a problem with for statement??

Adjusted code again, but not alert popup is all the time even if all the input fields got values?

Hello I am trying to validate a dynamic array of fields on a form:

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkReq();">
    <input value="" type="hidden" name="slider[]" id=""/>
</form>
```

with the following JavaScript, but it doesn't work? Could you tell me please what I am doing wrong.

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function checkReq () {
        var boxes = document.getElementsByName("slider[]");
    var ret = true;
    for (var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++) {

        if(boxes[x].value == '' || '0'){
            ret = false;
            break;
            } else {ret = true;} 

         }
   if (ret == false)
   {
     alert('Problem'); return ret;        
   }
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help.

```
function checkReq () {
     var boxes = document.getElementsByName("slider[]");
var ret = true;
for (var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++) {       
    if(boxes[x].value == '' || boxes[x].value == '0'){
        ret = false;
        break;
        } else {ret = true;} 

     }    
   if (ret == false)
   {
     alert('Problem'); return ret;        
   }
}
```

Comment: Now alert is on all the time, even if all the fields got value in them ? strange

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You are trying to compare element instead of it's value [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ5ym/3/)

```
function checkReq () {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName("slider[]");

    for (var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++) {

       if(boxes[x].value == '' || boxes[x].value == '0'){

            alert('Problem'); return false;

         } 
         else {return true;} 
    }
}
```

Comment: @FenixDolores press the submit button

Answer (score 0):

You always return after the first loop, so it doesn't go through each element (and thus redundant), is this intended?